# word extraction from n string user input in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to extract the words after , in a string.I have to done this for n number of strings from user input.I don't know how to do it? I just tried for a single string.Can anyone tell me how to do the same for n number of strings from the user?

```
     String str = "hi,34,55";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(.*?),", Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
             System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
            }
              System.out.print(" "+str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(",") + 1));
//get the string like this and extract only the numbers after ","
int n=in.nextInt();
String [] s=new String[44];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=in.nextLine();
        }
```

if n is 3 and the input string is "hi,1,2" ,   "hiii,2,3" ,   "ok,3,4" then the output will be 1 2 2 3 3 4 (i.e the number after ",")

This works properly it prints "34 55".Now we have to get the n value from user and get n strings and extract the words after "," in the input strings.

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you give an exmaple of an N and the output you'd want for it?

Comment: Are you going to store the inputs in an array?

Comment: @Mureinik i just edited my question.I think now it is clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to get a set of strings as input (with comma) and split each input try the following:

```
String[] strArray = null;
        String nArray[] = {"Hi1,1,2" ,"Hi3,3,4","Hi5,5,6"};

        for(int j=0 ;j < nArray.length ;j++) {

            strArray = str.split(",");
            for(int i = 1 ;i< strArray.length ;i++) {
                System.out.println(strArray[i]);
            }
        }
```

When printing the output start from counter 1 (i=1)

Answer (score 1):

Once you populate the list with InputStream input

```
        String[] str = {"ps, as, s", "ss,a, s"};

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            String[] samples = str[i].split(",");
            for(int j=0; j<samples.length; j++){

                words.add(samples[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);
```